# docker flask service is exited with code 3 in windows machine

Tags: windows, docker, flask, docker-compose, jinja2

I'm getting following message while executing docker-compose up in windows machine.

But the code is working good in Mac machine. Is this error specific to windows machine.?

```
-vue-1    | -  Building for production...
-neo4j-1  | 2022-04-02 19:44:04.451+0000 INFO  Starting...
-flask-1  | [2022-04-02 19:44:05 +0000] [7] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
-flask-1  | [2022-04-02 19:44:05 +0000] [7] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (7)
-flask-1  | [2022-04-02 19:44:05 +0000] [7] [INFO] Using worker: eventlet
-flask-1  | [2022-04-02 19:44:05 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
-flask-1  | [2022-04-02 19:44:05 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
-flask-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
-flask-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
-flask-1  |     worker.init_process()
-flask-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/geventlet.py", line 99, in init_process
-flask-1  |     super().init_process()
-flask-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
-flask-1  |     self.load_wsgi()
packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
-flask-1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
-flask-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
-flask-1  |     self.callable = self.load()
-flask-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
-flask-1  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
-flask-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
-flask-1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
-flask-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
-flask-1  |     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
-flask-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
-flask-1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
-flask-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
-flask-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
-flask-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
-flask-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
-flask-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
-flask-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
-flask-1  |   File "/app/flask/app.py", line 1, in <module>
-flask-1  |     from flask import Flask
-flask-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
-flask-1  |     from jinja2 import escape
-flask-1  | ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py)
-flask-1  | [2022-04-02 19:44:05 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
-flask-1  | [2022-04-02 19:44:05 +0000] [7] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
-flask-1  | [2022-04-02 19:44:05 +0000] [7] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to b
```

docker-compose up

I want to machine flask service up

Answer (score 0):

A new release of jinja 3.1 has caused some issues, try locking to a stable version. Try adding to requirments.txt
jinja2==3.0.3

Comment: Solved the problem after changing my Flask version as latest.